# Date Class and Exception Thrown

Tags: java, date, exception

Just need a quick help.

I am trying to use Java's built-in date class in object oriented programming. My question is what do I put in the data section of my class?

Currently, I have this:

```
    private double balance;
    private String name;
    private java.util.Date creationDate; (Wrong I know, but you get what I am tring to do here.)
    private boolean frozen;
    private double limit;
    private double MAXLIMIT;
    private int accountNumber;
    private static int howMany;
```

How do I go about naming the creationDate correctly?

Finally, my last question is it possible to throw an exception in a class and not main? All of the examples that my professor has shown in class are all in main or the driver. I was wonder is it possible to do so in my class, and if I can is it the same as in main i.e using try then catch etc.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is `private java.util.Date creationDate;` wrong?

Comment: methods throw exceptions ,classes don't

Comment: declaration of object never throw exceptions. but execution of method does.

Comment: Sorry, I meant throw exceptions in method not class. Still confused with the terminology in object oriented programming.

Comment: @Paincakes. There is nothing special about `main` or driver classes. You can throw exceptions from any methods as well as constructors. `try` and `catch` also work the same.

Comment: @Paul Boddington If that is the case, then I am assuming that all the way at the top I will still need "import java.util.*" ?

Comment: you don't need `import` if you use fully qualified name

Comment: @Ramanlfc Sorry, I meant throw exceptions in method not class. Still confused with the terminology in object oriented programmi

Comment: @Paul Boddington  Ok I got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have 2 choices. You can either write `java.util.Date` everywhere (annoying) or use an `import` statement (less annoying).

Comment: @Paul Boddington  I only have to do one Date in this program so I can do "java.util.Date". However, If I wanted to do the other way. How would I go about it?

Comment: no. If while declaration you have given complete reference of type, you will not need to import it then. But what you have posted here doesn't seem to relevant to the problem you are having.

Comment: You'd just put `import java.util.Date;` at the top and then you could just write `Date` from then on.

Comment: @Paul Boddington In my constructor how do I set `this.creationDate` to get the computer date? Do I do this `this.creationDate = getDate( );`?

Comment: @Paincakes I actually don't know. I've never used the Date class I'm afraid. I'd look at the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: @Paul Boddington Thanks for your help, greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it sounds like your question is: "How do I get my object to record know the date-time when it was instantiated, the current moment during construction?".

You have half the solution: A member variable defined on the class for each instance to record the current moment.

Unfortunately you are using the java.util.Date class which is outmoded as of Java 8. That class, and the related java.util.Calendar, are confusing and troublesome. Instead use the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. For your purpose, [java.time.Instant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is the way to go, capturing a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone.

Secondly, your class needs a constructor. This is automatically called whenever some code calls `new` for your class. In that constructor we capture the current moment.

Here is an example class. We have two member variables. The constructor performs a couple of checks on the passed account number and throws an exception if those checks failed (as you asked about in your Question).

Do try to ignore the `main` method while learning Java. That method is funky and confusing. Think of it a necessary evil needed just to solve the chicken-and-egg problem of getting the app started.

```
package com.example.javatimestuffmaven;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Account {

    String accountNumber;
    Instant whenInstantiated;

    public Account ( String accountNumber ) {
        if ( accountNumber == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "Null value passed as account number." );
        }
        if ( accountNumber.length () != 8 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "Value passed as account number is not 8 characters in length: " + accountNumber );
        }
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.whenInstantiated = Instant.now ();  // Grab the current date-time in UTC time zone.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "Account{ " + "accountNumber=" + accountNumber + " | whenInstantiated=" + whenInstantiated + " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        // Try to ignore the 'main' method.
        Account account = new Account ( "X4092253" );
        System.out.println ( "account: " + account );
    }

}
```

When run.

> account: Account{ accountNumber=X4092253 | whenInstantiated=2015-11-29T02:12:10.683Z }